# Select a word in texmaker with keyboard

Tags: texmaker

How can I select a word in texmaker using only the keyboard?

I'm looking for something that select the whole word (that must start and end with a whitespace) in one shot.

Right now with shift,cmd and arrows I'm able either to select the whole line or to select a single letter.

For instance in Sublime one can do what I want with cmd,shift,space. It's very useful since you don't need to be at the beginning of the word to select it.

I use Mac OS.

Comment: As in every other program: use the cursor, hold shift and then use the arrow keys.

Comment: erh, shift + arrow keys, like in most other editors?

Comment: If you Ctrl+F and look for that particular word, its first occurence will be selected as well.

Comment: @TeXnician In my editor, that won't work if the cursor is in the middle of the word.

Comment: @daleif ^^^^^^^

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select the word in one go, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is useful for this (especially for long words). Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hitting the left <kbd>←</kbd> (or right <kbd>→</kbd>) arrow key makes you go to the edge left (or right) of the word. This can be combined with <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select in the meantime.